# MySQL - Use Distinct in Where

Tags: mysql

I have am working with 2 columns, one that should be unique but has duplicates that i want to remove and one column that i need a count of the duplicates.  I have the second half of the equation figured out finally, but i still need to figure out how to remove the duplicates from the first column.

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(*) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM items i, hosts h, history_uint huint, mappings map
WHERE h.hostid=i.hostid AND h.name='$Hosts' AND i.itemid=huint.itemid AND i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid AND huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue
ORDER BY 'Item Name' DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The table.column that i am getting duplicate values from is `i.name`. Sorry if my query looks awful, I am just an IT guy pretending to know SQL.  Thank you for the assist!

Incase anyone else looks at this later in life, i am working on collecting phone models from Call Manager via SNMP and Zabbix and displaying it in Grafana.

Comment: See about JOINs. Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ah! good to know... i will put something together... thank you!

Comment: how do i add the MCVE? Sorry, i am very new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Luckily it's all explained in immense detail

Answer (score -1):

You can not use distinct in where clause but you can use group by for multiple column Try with this

```
SELECT map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(*) as 'Number of Phones'
FROM items i, hosts h, history_uint huint, mappings map
WHERE h.hostid=i.hostid AND h.name='$Hosts' AND i.itemid=huint.itemid AND i.valuemapid=map.valuemapid AND huint.value=map.value AND i.name LIKE '%Model of the Phone'
GROUP BY map.newvalue, i.name
ORDER BY 'Item Name' DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

It will change your result a bit because of adding extra filed in group by but it will give you unique name and newvalue result.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply but it does not seem to be giving me the correct output.  I do not think i am explaining myself very well.  I need unique values only from i.name, and a count of values from map.newvalue... but all i want to display on the output is the map.newvalue and a count of those.

Comment: if you want to display newvalue and their count only on the map then why you are looking for unique i.name field. 

can you display you real and expected output here.

Comment: Thank you for responding again.  I am working with a product called Zabbix that is for monitoring systems.  the "i" table are all the different items that it monitors for each system.  so "i.name" is referring to the name of a check.  Right now, i have a couple of checks that have the exact same name for some wierd reason even though the check includes the MAC address of a specific phone.  So one of the checks (i.name) returns a number that corresponds to a model of Cisco Phone in the mappings table

Comment: its really screwy.  I am looking for other ways to clean up my i.name list since those should be unique, but that is basically all i need it to do, go through the i table for name values and return only unique values from that table

Comment: I was looking into ways to add an inner join, but it seems a bit over my head for 2 am

Comment: thanks for clarification. in this case i think you should use i.name  in select statement you can use distinct their and it is totally up to you weather you want to call that field or not, try this.

`SELECT distinct i.name, map.newvalue as 'Model of Phone', Count(map.newvalue) as 'Number of Phones'`

but either way you will get unique i.name

In addition use `map.newvalue` for count row

Comment: When i try to add the distinct, i get a SQL error   

Error 1055: Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'zabbix.i.name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by